# Export seasonally removed individual VIIRS image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, viirs

I want to export particular (2nd month image of 2014) VIIRS image after removing seasonal variation from google earth engine. But the code showing error at 'dateString' which is:

```
Line 93: Collection.toList: Error in map(ID=20140101):
Image.pow, argument 'image2': Invalid type.
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>.
Actual type: Float.
Actual value: 0.0
```

The code is:

```js
var roi: Table projects/tensile-axiom-380702/assets/bangladeshh
// Define the start and end dates of the time series
var startDate = '2014-01-01';
var endDate = '2014-12-31';

// Load the VIIRS image collection
var viirs = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG')
              .select('avg_rad')
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
              .filterBounds(roi);

// Define the polynomial order for regression
var polynomialOrder = 3;

// Define a function to remove the seasonal component of the time series
var removeSeasonality = function(img) {
  var timeBand = img.metadata('system:time_start');
  
  // Create a time band
  var time = ee.Image(timeBand).rename('time');
  
  // Add the time band to the image
  var imgWithTime = img.addBands(time);
  
  // Create a list of polynomial terms
  var polynomialTerms = ee.List.sequence(0, polynomialOrder)
                         .map(function(exp) {
                           return time.pow(exp).rename('t' + exp);
                         });
  
  // Concatenate the polynomial terms to create a design matrix
  var designMatrix = ee.Image.cat(polynomialTerms);
  
  // Reshape the design matrix to match the image bands
  designMatrix = designMatrix.rename(['constant'].concat(img.bandNames()));
  
  // Flatten the image to a single band
  var imgFlattened = imgWithTime.select(['avg_rad']).rename(['response']);
  
  // Concatenate the response band with the design matrix
  var responseAndDesignMatrix = imgFlattened.addBands(designMatrix);
  
  // Perform linear regression to estimate the seasonal component
  var regression = responseAndDesignMatrix.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(polynomialOrder + 1),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 1000,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  // Extract the regression coefficients
  var coefficients = ee.Array(regression.get('coefficients'));
  
  // Extract the seasonal component from the regression coefficients
  var seasonalComponent = coefficients.slice(1, 2);
  
  // Calculate the fitted values using the design matrix and seasonal component
  var fittedValues = designMatrix.multiply(seasonalComponent).reduce('sum');
  
  // Subtract the fitted values from the original image to remove seasonality
  var seasonalityRemoved = imgFlattened.subtract(fittedValues);
  
  // Restore the original band name
  seasonalityRemoved = seasonalityRemoved.rename(img.bandNames().get(0));
  
  // Set the time band
  seasonalityRemoved = seasonalityRemoved.set('system:time_start', timeBand);
  
  return img.addBands(seasonalityRemoved).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
};
// Map the function over the image collection to remove seasonality from each image
var seasonalityRemoved = viirs.map(removeSeasonality);

// Get the count of images before seasonality removal
var countBefore = viirs.size();

// Get the count of images after seasonality removal
var countAfter = seasonalityRemoved.size();

// Print the counts
print('Number of images before seasonality removal:', countBefore);
print('Number of images after seasonality removal:', countAfter);



 // Export the second image (index 1) from the collection
var imageList = seasonalityRemoved.toList(seasonalityRemoved.size());
var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(1));
exportImage(image);

// Export image to Google Drive
function exportImage(image) {
  var dateString = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo();
  var exportName = 'viirs_seasonality_removed_' + dateString;
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.select('avg_rad'),
    description: exportName,
    folder: 'GEE_export',
    scale: 1000,
    region: roi,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
}
```